# Henkin Construction: Goedel completeness Theorem

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand better the Henkin construction, which consist first in an extension of the signature and then of the theory.

Here are my question about this topic:

- we extend the signature with "special constants" giving two first rules (first a closed term is a special constant). Why do we need special constant and why we choose them?
- we next States that for n&m natural numbers and $<t_0,...,t_{n-1}>$ an $n$-tuple of special constants so $(n,t_0,...,t_{n-1},m)$ is a special constant.
  for what is this useful?

I think I am missing the target here. Why we want to extend our signature, why we use special constants and for what is useful this second rule?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Especially your second point concerning the $n$-tuples of "special constants" is not clear to me (and in fact, I've never seen anything comparable in the context of the Henkin construction). Could you provide a reference for that?

Comment: I do not have a reference... I wish I had one. That comes from the lecture class. I can only say what next comes. In fact this form will be coded in a 0-1-6-8-9 sequence and this coding will give a order on these "special constants". Next will be introduced the concept of witness ($(n,t_0,...,t_{n-1},m)$ is a witness for a $\sigma_m$ statement if $\sigma_m$ in special prenex normal form, $\exists v_n" appears in $\sigma_m$ and for all $k<n$ If $\exists v_k appears then $t_k$ is a witness for $\sigma_m$.)